# Custom iOS popup/modal view jailbreak launch daemon

Tags: ios, uiview, popup, daemon, jailbreak

I'm working on a jailbreak tweak (launch daemon) that simply listens for a certain event then will need to display a custom popup UIView when that event occurs. The popup needs to appear wherever - so either lockscreen, springboard or in app.

Whilst I have managed to get a simple `CFUserNotificationDisplayAlert` working, it does not offer the required functionality - I would prefer a custom view to be rendered.

I have tried using the `RNBlurModalView` library [here](https://github.com/rnystrom/RNBlurModalView), but this crashes when attempting to render the view as it looks for a base `UIViewController` - there isn't one as it's a background daemon.

Does anyone have any tips how I can go about rendering a custom popup view (whether it's modifying the above `RNBlur` library or rolling a different solution)?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is inject a dynamic library into SpringBoard in which you use [the `CPDistributedMessagingCenter` class](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/CPDistributedMessagingCenter) in server mode and you set it up in a way so that it listens for a message, then upon receiving that message, its observer object renders the custom view and adds it to the key window of the SpringBoard application itself (`[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:customView];`).

Then, in the other part of the tweak (where you're currently calling `CFUserNotificationDisplayAlert()`), you simply use `CPDistributedMessagingCenter` in client mode and send it the appropriate message whenever needed.